# ruby - require 'pg' not working on OSX

Tags: ruby

(This has got to be a UFU)

Simple piece of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'pg'

# use postgres
```

Then I run:

```
(shell)> gem install pg
```

It says:

> gem install pg
>   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   Successfully installed pg-0.18.1
>   invalid options: -f fivefish
>   (invalid options are ignored)
>   Parsing documentation for pg-0.18.1
>   Done installing documentation for pg after 1 seconds
>   1 gem installed

Now I run my app:

`(shell)>./update.rb`

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- pg (LoadError)
>       from   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from ./update.rb:3:in `'

I've tried using a **Gemfile/bundle install** too - same result.

I'm doing something foolish here - just can't seem to see it.

---

Edit:
postgres is installed:

> postgres --version
>   postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.4.1

---

Edit:
Tried the same setup on a CentOS 6.5 machine. Same result(s). Clearly I'm missing some major step / component.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/wiki/MacOSXInstructions) instruction? I think, it can help you.

Comment: may be your installation of pg is not belongs to `/usr/`, may be /usr/local or somewhere else.

Comment: I think that may be the problem. Put it in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your installation of pg is not belongs to `/usr/`, may be `/usr/local` or somewhere else.

Comment: When I checked what I was using in the .rb file to where ruby was *actually installing* things.. it was a head slap for sure.